# Cannot figure out view models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do a viewmodel correctly. We have two models, tblInventory and tblGlobalhardware, both of which need to be shown on the Details page of an inventory item, based on the InventoryID (Primary key in tblInventory and is a column in tblGlobalhardware).

I've followed numerous tutorials but get errors such about the model etc when changed on the view.

Can anyone possibly point me in the direction of a basic, easy to follow tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC you usually pass a single model instance to the view. You want to show details of the product and the inventory. So you create a view model type:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can bind your view to this type and display the data from both objects. Just create an instance with the desired values in your controller and send it to the view:

```
var viewModel = new ProductViewModel { Inventory = inventory, Product = product};
return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It doesn't give any errors, but anything from the tblGlobalHardware table doesn't shown when I do Model => Model.GlobalHardware.ComputerOS for example

Comment: @SouthWilts Can you debug it and see if you get the values from database correctly?

Comment: Have put a break point on @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.GlobalHardware.ComputerOS) and it stops debugging when it gets to that point.

Comment: @SouthWilts Put a breakpoint in your controller when you are creating the viewmodel instance.

Comment: Still nothing, just stops dead there with hit count at 0. Should I move this into chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78178/discussion-between-south-wilts-and-ufuk-haciogullari).